# HTTP::Daemon and debug error codes

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, network-programming

How can I debug error codes when the daemon itself can not be initialized:

```
my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalAddr=>$ae::Settings{ip},
                       LocalPort=>$ae::Settings{port},
                       ReuseAddr=>'1') || die "error";
```

What I would like is more specific error codes instead of a simple 'die'. For example if I can't bind to certain ports, *etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not root and I run this against a privileged ( < 1024 ) port or against a higher port that is already in use:

```
#!perl
# HTTP_daemon.pl 

use HTTP::Daemon;      
use warnings;      
my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new(LocalAddr=>"127.0.0.1", 
                       LocalPort=>"88",     
                       ReuseAddr=>'1') || die "$!";
```

I get:

```
Permission denied at HTTP_daemon.pl line 4.
```

For errors and status codes related to HTTP use [`HTTP::Status`](http://www.metacpan.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can just check `$!` (i.e. the errno from the underlying system call) for problems while initializing the underlying socket. And more than creating the listener is not done inside `HTTP::Daemon::new`

```
HTTP::Daemon->new(...) or die "error: $!"
```